# Bugs in Blender 2.83.0

Tags: edit-mode

I am getting this type of effect in edit mode in letest version of Blender 2.83.0

Should I switch back to 2.82.7 or is there any solution to this bug?

[image]

Comment: I get similar in Edit mode. Perhaps 2.83 isn't quite ready yet.

Comment: What is your GPU and have you tried updating the graphics driver?

Comment: @RobertGützkow I have Intel HD5000 GPU, but that should not be an issue as all drivers are updated and Blender 2.82.7 is still working fine.

Comment: Technically it is an issue with the Intel HD GPUs, but Clément has implemented and committed a workaround. See [T76273](https://developer.blender.org/T76273) for the bug report and [rBf71a2fc6c381f32e89ac09112ac3b7ebc3f8a794](https://developer.blender.org/rBf71a2fc6c381f32e89ac09112ac3b7ebc3f8a794) for the fix. The patch will likely be included in the next corrective release of 2.83 LTS. As a workaround you can disable anti-aliasing in the user preferences to avoid the artifacts.

Comment: @RobertGützkow Thank you, It was really helpful, now view is ok, but I guess still I may face problem with some other features. I may need to upgrad my system.